# Command Line One-Liners: Quick & Dirty "Bytes Transferred" report

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

Alright.  So we have a lighttpd server pumping out the loading of our images.

It logs on a daily basis, and we're considering moving all those images to our S3 account for better load times, but before we can do that i need to get atleast a "feel" for what our transfer will look like.

So right now we have the standard lighttp access log

> accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/images.access_log"
>   accesslog.format = "%h %V %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""

so want to dump all the "bytes transferred" from that log file, nice and easy.

> cat images.access_log | awk '{print $10}'

which kicks out a output similar to this.

```
19547
6138
17782
8044
345
0
2727
2125
1838
1649
2127
3275
3653
0
16688
```

Now -- I've done a bit of googling and maybe i'm forgetting something, is there a command hidden away in linux somewhere that will take all that output, and just add it all together for me? so i can run this command and just have it spit out an absurdly large number every day until i get a baseline of our bandwidth per day?

--- EDIT ---

i Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/linux-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line

IS there anyway to get awk to return the full number, instead of doing what is shown below?

```
cat images.access_log | awk '{print $10}' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' 
9.48886e+10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cat images.access_log | awk '{print $10}' | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.f\n",s}'`

Answer (score 5):

You can combine these into one command.  If the 10th column has the numbers, then:

```
awk '{s+=$10} END {printf("%.d\n",s)}' images.access_log
```

Comment: +1 for killing unnecessary `cat`ing and piping.